# Matlab vector Printing

Tags: matlab, vector, printf

How do i print a vector in matlab with also something before the values. For example i have a vector with the following values A' = [1 2 3]. I want to print it out in such a way that the output will be

```
w0 = 1

w1 = 2

w2 = 3
```

How do i do this?

Can i do this using a loop?

I am using the following code and i am not getting the right output

```
for qux = 1:3
    fprintf('w%i=%.4lf\n',qux-1,answ);
end
```

Output:

```
w0=w1=w2
```

Answer (score 1):

Your format string is not formed properly. Specifically `'%.4lf'` should be `'%.4f'`. Additionally, the third input to `fprintf` should be `A(qux)` to access the value in `A`.

```
for qux = 1:3
    fprintf('w%i=%.4f\n', qux-1, A(qux));
end
```

I would, however, recommend using `'%g'` to use a format that optimizes the display of each number. Additionally, you could remove the `for` loop and do something like

```
A = [1, 2, 3];

fprintf('w%i = %g\n', [0:numel(A)-1; A])
```

Comment: i did this and got the same output.

Comment: @user9930 You should check that the value of `A` is what you expect. Also make sure you are using the latest edit.

Comment: my vector using standard outputs with each number in a new line:
    0.8171

   -1.6794

         0

Comment: @user9930 I don't understand your last post.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understand the question correctly, I think that you could do that with the following code:

```
for i = 1:3
    disp(['w' num2str(A(i)-1) '=' num2str(A(i))]);
end
```

Using `disp` and `num2str` you could get the following output:

```
w0=1
w1=2
w2=3
```